# InfoPath versus ASP form

Tags: 2013, infopath, asp.net, custom-form

Environment: SP2013 Enterprise, InfoPath 2010

My question is hopefully pretty straight-forward, but I haven't found any good documentation on it so I'm looking for advice from personal experience if possible. Basically, is there a point at which a form's requirements can become so large as to necessitate a completely custom ASP form as opposed to simply using InfoPath? The form I'm working on (in InfoPath until now) has become so monstrous (~300 fields that all interact with each other somehow) that I'm nervous about IP being able to handle it. Before I scrap it and try to redesign the entire thing as a visual web part form, does anyone know the actual practical limits of IP in this respect? Are my concerns justified?

Answer (score 1):

I am not involve in IP form designing but i know one of our department create IP form with tons of fields which slow down their site collection. Personally, As we know, this is last version of IP so i think better to design in ASP.net or access form.

Check this post, they discuss couple of limitation.
[Disadvantages of implementing InfoPath in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39954/disadvantages-of-implementing-infopath-in-sharepoint)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7f47ec57-a292-40b7-8759-cdc2e8bed2cd/fields-capacity-or-limitations-for-infopath-2010-browser-based-form

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/InfoPath%20Forms%20vs%20ASP.NET%20Forms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The good thing with using ASP.NET is you can write your own logic and customize it whenever needed with much flexibility. It is relatively difficult than using InfoPath as we have to be concerned about the page life-cycle a lot. Also you can manage it easily with asp:view controllers when a large amount of components are there. (In your case 300)

But on the  other hand using InfoPath gives the easy to change facility and of course it more importantly become useful when connecting with services such like Microsoft Dynamics and many other MS products. Because they prefer the xsn format. It also make things editable easily unlike aspx forms where you need to compile sometimes.

My suggestion is in case of not such requirement of connecting to an existing xsn format preferred service and many fields are present, go with aspx forms.